# Can I store extra data in a Guid

Tags: c#, .net, string, guid

Can we implement a custom GUID in C# with string values and again fetch the custom string data from GUID parsing? It may not sound practical, but just to know the process and its de-merits.

Suppose we have a database table *CUSTOMER* with **Cust_Data** column as uniqueidentifier datatype. From C#, we created method to generate GUID and put in DB table. for example

```
public Guid GetCustomGuid(Guid guidValue , string customerData)
{
 // Method implementation
 // Create New GUID as ==> guidValue + customerData;
 return //Guid created
}
```

Once the GUID is generated , we again parse the GUID from DB and fetch the customer data.

```
public string GetCustomData(Guid GuidFromDB)
{
  // Method implementation for parsing the guid.
  // fetch the custom data from GuidFromDB.
  // Every GUID received is always unique with respect to customer  data.
  return //CustomerData;
 }
```

I didn't know whether, I put the question exact context, please edit it, if required.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. A GUID does not have any extra space for custom data.

Comment: `Every GUID received is always unique with respect to customer data.` That's not a GUID, then. Any GUID is guaranteed to be unique *with respect to all the other GUIDs*.

Comment: A guid is a guid, but instead you could create your own custom data type with a guid and a string field...

Comment: `"It may not sound practical"` - It really doesn't.  What's the problem being solved here?  There's likely a better way to solve it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I actually meant that GUID values always keep on changing for different customer data.

Comment: @user, is your customer data unique? (e.g. is it different for all your customers?) If that's the case, you could implement [named-based GUIDs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.3) from that data. Beware of hash collisions, though.

Comment: Why embed customer data in a GUID?   Put customer data in it's own column.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

A column of type *uniqueidentifier* can store 16 bytes.  This is in general not enough to leave room for extra data and is **certainly** not in anyway suitable to ensure that the column is still unique once you start dropping bytes from the Guid to make room.  There's no GU in guid anymore when you do that, it is no longer guaranteed to be globally unique.  The random index collisions you get are of course very unpleasant.

There's no point, just add an extra column to the table.  Maybe you want a clustered index, it isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

One of this biggest reasons NOT to do this is because if the GUID is relative to some customer data, and you change that data, you change the Guid.  This would break [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) in the database.  Row Identifers are not support to, in and of themselves, contain data about row, only how the row is related to other rows.